# Jquery AJAX JSON "parsererror" Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am performing an AJAX call when a user tries to bookmark and article on my website. This has been working and I have no idea what could have changed. I am returning JSON and the call errors with error "parsererror". There are no other details. I test the PHP code in background and it works fine, no issues. I read several posts on this topic and it mentioned to add "header('Content-type: application/json');" which I did and still no luck. When I test in the background, I receive response {"status":"X","new_token":"9b5a824a"}.

**Script**

```
    $(document).on("click","#bookmark",function(a){
    a.preventDefault();
    var t=$(this).attr("bookmark_id"),
    e=$("input[name=token").val(),
    s=$(this);
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"bookmark",
        data:{token:e,bookmarkid:t},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            if(data.status == 'X')
            {
                s.find("i").addClass("green");
                $("input#token").val(data.new_token);
                s.removeAttr("href");
            }
        },
        error : function(request,error)
        {
            alert(error);
        }
    })
}),
```

**Codeigniter PHP Code**

```
    public function bookmark()
{
    $this->load->model('User_model');
     if($this->User_model->add_bookmark($this->input->post('bookmarkid')))
        {
            $data['jsondata']['status']    = 'X';
            $data['jsondata']['new_token'] = $this->tokens->token();
            $this->load->view('json_view', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            $data['jsondata']['status']    = '';
            $data['jsondata']['new_token'] = $this->tokens->token();
            $this->load->view('json_view', $data);
        }
}
```

**JSON View**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($jsondata);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't have to render the view file for an ajax call.

**Controller :**

```
public function bookmark()
{
    $this->load->model('User_model');
     if($this->User_model->add_bookmark($this->input->post('bookmarkid')))
        {
            $data = array('status' => 'X','new_token' => $this->tokens->token());
        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('status' => '','new_token' => $this->tokens->token());
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: I removed the type as GET since it should be POST as the passed parameter for BookmarkID was NULL when posting to the DB. Now I receive error "Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data" and console shows a POST and GET

Comment: I somehow fixed, I used the suggestion from M. Deepak and I also put my data parameters in single quotes and removed the space between dataType: "json",. Now working except for the update of the hidden token element but I will figure that out.